# What privileges are needed to restart jenkins successfully from the web interface?

Tags: jenkins, windows-service, user-permissions

I'm having an issue when I try to restart Jenkins using the web interface (either through http(s)://theserver/restart or http(s)://theserver/saferestart) because Jenkins gets stuck on the screen "Please wait while Jenkins is restarting Your browser will reload automatically when Jenkins is ready." and the service never shows as stopped so we have to manually go to the server's Services and stop/start or restart the Jenkins Windows service in order to get Jenkins ready again.

Our Jenkins server (current version is 2.60.3) runs on Windows2012R2, the Jenkins process runs as a Windows service with a technical account (domain\sirjenkins) that has limited privileges.

When the technical account that runs the process is an administrator, Jenkins restarts normally after a minute of the "please wait" messages.

The privileges I have assigned to the domain\sirjenkins account are: - Member of the Users group in the server - Full control permissions on the jenkins config files - Full control permissions on the jenkins workspace folders - Right to "Log on as a service" in the Local Security Policy

Everything else on the Jenkins web interface and the automated processes (other than restarting from the web interface) works without any problems when using this account to run the Jenkins Windows service.

I've been searching online for a similar issue but most of what I've found are issues related to not being able to start Jenkins at all because of configuration issues/bugs, or suggestions to assign the privileges I've already assigned to that account. Further testing has proved that Jenkins has no problems in starting with the restricted privileges it has been given, but it runs into trouble just trying to stop itself successfully during the web restart.

Has anybody else faced this issue and is there any user right we might be missing in the "local security policy" for the account that runs Jenkins as a service to be able to restart Jenkins from the web interface successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What I use to restart Jenkins, is the following pipeline script:

```
import jenkins.model.*
sleep 15
Jenkins.instance.doSafeRestart(null);
```

Just create a new "Pipeline" type job, paste the code above and make sure you uncheck the "Use Groovy Sandbox" checkbox.

In my configuration, the service account has additional privileges, but this approach may also work for a restricted account.

You can also assign per-project user privileges to "build" (actually, run) this job, using the [Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Authorization+Strategy+Plugin), or schedule the job to run periodically.